# Codeigniter HMVC: Undefined property $db in model

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-hmvc

Here is the folder structure in `modules` folder

1. users->controllers->Users.php

   users->models->Test_model.php
2. welcome->controllers->Welcome.php

**Test_model.php**

class Test_model extends CI_Model {

```
 function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function db_example()
{
     return $this->db->get('mir_users')->result();
}
public function test(){
    echo 'test model call';
}
```

}

and in **Welcome.php**

```
class Welcome extends MX_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('users/test_model');
    }
    public function index()
    {
      //this will give the output   
      $this->test_model->test();
     //thiw will throw error
        $this->test_model->db_example();
    }
```

`$this->test_model->test()` returns the output  but i will get the error  in `db_example` function

```
Message: Undefined property: Test::$db
```

In  `autoload.php`

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

I am using the latest version of `HMVC`

Codeigniter version :3.1.0

Comment: Is there a folder named users in models?

Comment: Nop there is no folder in `models` folder

Comment: $this->load->model('users/test_model'); why did you put users in this statement?

Comment: This loads a model from another module

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. The problem is not with my code. It's with the HMVC version.

For codeigniter versions 3.x use this version https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/downloads?tab=branches

But I used the wrong version.

Answer (score 1):

You have loaded database library two times in the autoload and in the model comment this line in model

```
$this->load->database();
```